# Como hacer print de una búsqueda regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, regex, dataframe

Intento hacer una búsqueda regex de la columan de un DataFrame (dejo como ejemplo una sample en forma de serie) con el siguiente bloque de código

```
x = pd.Series(["Full HD 1920x1080", "IPS Panel Full HD / Touchscreen 1920x1080", "Full HD 1920x1080", "1366x768", "1366x768"])
patron = re.compile(r"/d/d/d/dx/d/d/d/d")
lista = []
for i in x:
    match = patron.finditer(i)
    lista.append(match)
print(lista)
```

El problema se presenta que no se guarda como la búsqueda en si, sino que cada match se guarda de la siguiente manera y no se porque

```
<callable_iterator at 0x20c39ac2700>
```

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pattern.finditer()` devuelve un iterador que genera un [objeto `Match`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/re.html#match-objects) con toda la información de una coincidencia en el string.

Para obtener todo el texto con el que coincidió, se usa **`match.group()`**.

```
patron = re.compile(r'\d{3,4}x\d{3,4}')
lista = []
for i in x:
    match = patron.finditer(i)
    for m in match:   #para cada una de las coincidencias de cada item
        lista.append(m.group())
```

Además, como comentario, cuando sólo te interesa la primera coincidencia, en vez de usar `Pattern.finditer()`, se puede llamar a [`Pattern.search()`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.search).

Comment: Me devuelve esto: AttributeError: 'callable_iterator' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Pasa por escribir sin pensar... Ahí lo modifiqué

Comment: Muchas gracais máquina!